# No exception with bound dropdownlist text setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following is not generating an error so, I can't test a success or failure.  Visual Studio's setting maybe?

```
try
{
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Cnt");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(i);
    }
    DrpLevel.DataTextField = "Cnt";
    DrpLevel.DataValueField = "Cnt";
    DrpLevel.DataSource = dt;
    DrpLevel.DataBind();
    DrpLevel.Text = "777";  //Should cause error!!
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `DrpLevel.Text = "777";` should throw error? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Where do you run this code? Is it in a _IsPostBack==true_ section?

Answer (score 0):

If you run that code when the Page.IsPostBack property is false then you don't get an exception. This is also explained in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) of SelectedValue (The Text property just calls SelectedValue to get/set)

> When the selected value is not in the list of available values and a
>   postback is performed, an ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception is
>   thrown.

If we take a look at the [source code of SelectedValue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/ListControl.cs,383) we can see this check

```
bool loaded = Page != null && Page.IsPostBack && _stateLoaded;
if (loaded && selectItem == null) {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", SR.GetString(SR.ListControl_SelectionOutOfRange, ID, "SelectedValue"));
}
```

So, when IsPostBack is false or the control has not yet loaded the ViewState we don't get any exception.